# How to check a column and return if specified word is found and which cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have a small production team and when people finish their work I want them to input into our sheet they finished their set of work. Is there a way for Google Sheets to auto-update or refresh every 5 minutes and tell me, for example, if cell A15 and cell A35 were completed, play a sound and tell me what cells were completed?

Answer (score 1):

Do the Notification rules (in Tools) work for what you want?

[image]

[image]